# Bootstrap Column sizes Toggling using jQuery Clickable

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap 3 with Panels.

I have 4 Columns per row with "`<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">`". Inside heading I have 3 links namely   `12  |  6  |  3` on each panel.

1. If I click on  `12` from heading, this Panel should stretch to **100%**
   width.. means this panel should become "`<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">`" and other 3 panels will be "`<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">`"
2. If I click on  `6` from heading, this Panel should stretch to **50%**
   width.. means this panel should become "`<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">`" and other 3 panels will be "`<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">`"
3. If I click on  `3` from heading, this Panel should stretch to **25%**
   width.. means all 4 panels should become "`<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">`"

---

### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/99b28z9y/4/)

---

> **HTML**

```
<!-- Container -->
<div class="container-fluid">

    <!-- Row -->
    <div class="row">

        <!-- Column 1 -->
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">

            <!-- Panel 1 -->
            <div class="panel panel-default">

                <!-- Panel Heading -->
                <div class="panel-heading">

                    <h3 class="panel-title">Panel 1</h3> <!-- Heading -->

                    <!-- Settings -->
                    <div class="pt-right">
                        <a href="#" class="full-width">12</a><a href="#" class="half-width">6</a><a href="#" class="custom-width" class="active">3</a>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /Settings -->

                </div>
                <!-- /Panel Heading -->

                <div class="panel-body">Panel 1 Content</div> <!-- Panel Content -->

            </div>
            <!-- /Panel 1 -->

        </div>
        <!-- /Column 1 -->

        <!-- Column 2 -->
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">

            <!-- Panel 2 -->
            <div class="panel panel-default">

                <!-- Panel Heading -->
                <div class="panel-heading">

                    <h3 class="panel-title">Panel 2</h3> <!-- Heading -->

                    <!-- Settings -->
                    <div class="pt-right">
                        <a href="#" class="full-width">12</a><a href="#" class="half-width">6</a><a href="#" class="custom-width" class="active">3</a>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /Settings -->

                </div>
                <!-- /Panel Heading -->

                <div class="panel-body">Panel 2 Content</div> <!-- Panel Content -->

            </div>
            <!-- /Panel 2 -->

        </div>
        <!-- /Column 2 -->

        <!-- Column 3 -->
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">

            <!-- Panel 3 -->
            <div class="panel panel-default">

                <!-- Panel Heading -->
                <div class="panel-heading">

                    <h3 class="panel-title">Panel 3</h3> <!-- Heading -->

                    <!-- Settings -->
                    <div class="pt-right">
                        <a href="#" class="full-width">12</a><a href="#" class="half-width">6</a><a href="#" class="custom-width" class="active">3</a>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /Settings -->

                </div>
                <!-- /Panel Heading -->

                <div class="panel-body">Panel 3 Content</div> <!-- Panel Content -->

            </div>
            <!-- /Panel 3 -->

        </div>
        <!-- /Column 3 -->

        <!-- Column 4 -->
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">

            <!-- Panel 4 -->
            <div class="panel panel-default">

                <!-- Panel Heading -->
                <div class="panel-heading">

                    <h3 class="panel-title">Panel 4</h3> <!-- Heading -->

                    <!-- Settings -->
                    <div class="pt-right">
                        <a href="#" class="full-width">12</a><a href="#" class="half-width">6</a><a href="#" class="custom-width" class="active">3</a>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /Settings -->

                </div>
                <!-- /Panel Heading -->

                <div class="panel-body">Panel 4 Content</div> <!-- Panel Content -->

            </div>
            <!-- /Panel 4 -->

        </div>
        <!-- /Column 4 -->

    </div>
    <!-- /Row -->

</div>
<!-- /Container -->
```

> **jQuery (Tried below code, and not able to get it right)**

```
$('.full-width').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('[class^="col-md"], [class^="col-sm"], [class^="col-xs"]').removeClass('col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6').addClass('col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple demo, try:

```
$('div.pt-right a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var size = $(this).text();
    var pclass, oclass;
    if (size == 12) {
        pclass = 'col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12';
        oclass = 'col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4';
    }
    if (size == 6) {
        pclass = 'col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6';
        oclass = 'col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2';
    }
    if (size == 3) {
        pclass = oclass = 'col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3';
    }
    var spanel = $(this).parents('div.panel').parent()
    spanel.removeClass().addClass(pclass);
    $('.panel').parent().not(spanel).removeClass().addClass(oclass);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/99b28z9y/6/)

Comment: **@Alex**, sorry this is not working :(... I want to toggle the panel classes `col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12` .. Thanks for your effort

Comment: Thanks **@Alex**, onClick only this panel is working as expected... but I want other panels also should change their class to different.. please check my description..

Comment: click one panel, all of panels change class?

Comment: Sorry... If I click on `12` from Panel 1, this panel's parent div classes should be changed to `<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">` _this is working great now_... and at the same time, other panel's (_Panel 2, Panel 3 and Panel 4_) parent classes should be changed to `<div class="col-lg-4  col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">`... And If I click on 6, this panel parent div clasees will become `<div class="col-lg-6  col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">` where as other panel's parent clasees will be `<div class="col-lg-2  col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">` etc...